Generating the same SHA-256 code_challenge as Postman using Java
When working on new HTTP request in Postman v11.2.14-canary01, and going to the Authorization tab and selecting SHA-256 for the Code Challenge Method and putting
6b890b254542c9de4603278153e1b127d21730d46ac2620e6e35514c
in the Code Verifier field, I can see that the https call says:
code_challenge=EKhdok_1ZKtBrevixgZqXxEHxn5pQjKkFA4bTVOmyH4
I'm trying to recreate this in Java.
        String text = "6b890b254542c9de4603278153e1b127d21730d46ac2620e6e35514c";
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
        String value = encoder.encodeToString(hash);
        System.out.println("Result [" + value + "]");

Results in
Result [EKhdok/1ZKtBrevixgZqXxEHxn5pQjKkFA4bTVOmyH4=]

The results do not match.  What are the specifics that should be used to "clean-up" the result?

It's using a Base64 URL encoding. Change
Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();

to
Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getUrlEncoder();

With that one change, I get (as expected)
Result [EKhdok_1ZKtBrevixgZqXxEHxn5pQjKkFA4bTVOmyH4=]

The trailing = is padding.
